# safe JSON parsing. How JSON parse can parse UTF characters?

Tags: javascript, json, character-encoding

Hello I am wondering why this line doesn't work:

```js
JSON.parse({"a":"\u00A9"})
```

I tried to serach in MDN website but I didn't find anything referring to in json.parse

Unicode escaping is syntactically legal in js according to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#String_literals

What is the problem and how can I safely parse text with JSON.parse

Answer (score 2):

`{"a":"\u00A9"}` is a JavaScript object literal.

`JSON.parse` expects to be passed a string so it is implicitly converted to a string (`"[object Object]"`).

The `[` is fine, because a JSON text can start with an array.

The `o` is then an error because it isn't allowed there.

---

A literal copyright symbol (remember that `\u00A9` inside a JavaScript string literal will be consumed by the JS parser before it gets to the JSON parser) or the unicode escape sequence would be fine.

```js
console.log(JSON.parse('{"a":"\u00A9"}'));
console.log(JSON.parse('{"a":"\\u00A9"}'));
```

---

Note that creating a string literal in JS source code that contains JSON and then parsing it is a terrible idea. You have to deal with nested levels of escaping, and it is inefficient.

If you have an object: use the object.

```js
var data = {"a":"\u00A9"};
console.log(data.a);
```

Comment: How could I parse the object literal? Should I stringify it first? Would you recommend something for "safe parsing", Thanks a lot for your answer it is really helpful

Comment: Ok u added code will check it and mark solution if ok

Comment: If you have an object literal then **just use the object**. Converting it to JSON is pointless unless you want to export it out of JS.